# Ways of creating tunnel in saucelabs apart from setting up proxy method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

As I am new to Saucelabs, I am looking for a way to create the Tunnel in Saucelabs to run my selenium scripts. I found a way to set up a proxy in Suacelab by downloading the tunnel for the respective operating system and running a few commands. But instead of downloading the tunnel, Is there any way to create it, like by using any other plugins like Maven dependencies or APIs?